# Must set dist.jar

Tags: netbeans, java-me, netbeans-7, midp-2.0

I am getting following error while building j2me application in netbean 7.0.1

```
D:\Netbean_proj\Avvaiyar\nbproject\build-impl.xml:62: Must set dist.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How to solve this, i googled lot but didn't find proper answer. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Open project properties > Build > Creating JAR, then set JAD and JAR filename to something like mymidlet.jad and mymidlet.jar (in my case they both were set to "null")

Or you can add it directly to nbproject/project.properties:

```
dist.jad=javame.jad
dist.jar=javame.jar
```